# C++ template copy constructor on template class

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor

I have a template class that has a template copy constructor. The problem is when I instantiate this class using another instance of this class with the same template type, my template copy constructor is not called. Why doesn't it match?

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class MyTemplateClass
{
    public:
        MyTemplateClass()
        {
            std::cout << "default constructor" << std::endl;
        }

        /*
        MyTemplateClass(const MyTemplateClass<T>& other)
        {
            std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
        }
        */

        template <typename U>
        MyTemplateClass(const MyTemplateClass<U>& other)
        {
            std::cout << "template copy constructor" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    MyTemplateClass<int> instance;
    MyTemplateClass<int> instance2(instance);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is

```
default constructor
```

But if I explicitly write the default copy constructor (by uncommenting it), then the output becomes

```
default constructor
copy constructor
```

I really don't get it. I tested it with my local compiler (Clang 500.2.79) and with [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php) (GCC 4.9.2) and got the same result.

Comment: A template is never (!) a copy constructor!

Comment: A copy constructor is never a template.

Comment: There's an implicitly declared copy constructor that's preferred by overload resolution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A copy constructor is of the form `X(X& )` or `(X const&)` and will be provided for you by the compiler if you didn't declare one yourself (or a few other conditions which are not relevant here). You didn't, so implicitly we have the following set of candidates:

```
MyTemplateClass(const MyTemplateClass&);
template <typename U> MyTemplateClass(const MyTemplateClass<U>&);
```

Both are viable for

```
MyTemplateClass<int> instance2(instance);
```

Both take the same exact arguments. The issue isn't that your copy constructor template doesn't *match*. The issue is that the implicit copy constructor is not a function template, and non-templates are preferred to template specializations when it comes to overload resolution. From [over.match.best], omitting the unrelated bullet points:

> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>   F2 if for all arguments i, ICS<sub>i</sub>(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICS<sub>i</sub>(F2), and then 
>   — [...] 
>   — F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function template specialization, or, if not that, 
>   — [...]

That's why it calls your implicit (and then, your explicit) copy constructor over your constructor template.

Comment: Why are non-templates preferred to template specializations when it comes to overload resolution? Is it because in most cases that's the best strategy to choose?

Comment: @REACHUS The direct answer is because that is the rule (added standard quote). The general rule is - pick the most specific function possible. The non-template is more specific than the template.

Comment: Ok tanks, my mistake was to think that no copy constructor would be generated.

Answer (score 2):

When you do not have a copy constructor in you code, the compiler will implicitly generate it. Therefore when this line is executed:

```
MyTemplateClass<int> instance2(instance);
```

A copy constructor *is* being executed, though obviously not yours. I think that templating has nothing to do with it.

Read more about it here: [Implicitly-defined copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-defined_copy_constructor)

Answer (score -1):

I think REACHUS is right. The compiler is generating a default copy-constructor (as it would with a non-template class too) and preferring this over your template as it's more specialised.

You should make your "normal" copy-constructor private, or better, use the C++11 'deleted' keyword to mark the function as unusable.

However, this doesn't compile. Sorry, I wasn't able to test it at the time.

Comment: Both of those suggestions would make the code fail to compile - not prefer to call the constructor template.

Comment: @Barry Why do you think it is not a good idea to declare a deleted copy constructor in this case?

Comment: @REACHUS That would make the class noncopyable. I do not believe that to be the OP's goal.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't compile for me, but why does the compiler try to use the deleted function in lieu of the template?

Comment: Who is *"REACHUS"*? (A user may have changed screenname.)