# Why is the destructor of this custom allocator being called twice in GCC/MSVS's stdlib

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, libstdc++, allocator

I've been trying to write a simple allocator, I've written a minimal one that just logs its calls.

When trying to use it in some simple `std::vector` operations - at least on GCC and Visual Studio - the logged behaviour looks intuitive except that the destructor appears to be called before all of the allocations are requested, as well as at the end. On clang everything works as one would expect, so I'm not sure if this is just a compiler issue.

Assuming it's not a compiler error, what's missing from this allocator; or is my understanding of how the allocator is being called wrong and it's just fine?

I have the code below as a live demo [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j5fIPfo6hM3dL7yg)

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::size_t;

struct Indexer
{
    static size_t nextId, objectsAlive;
};

size_t Indexer::nextId, Indexer::objectsAlive;

template<typename T>
class DebugAllocator : protected Indexer
{
    static std::string formatPointer(const void* p)
    {
        std::ostringstream s;
        s << "[93m0x" << std::hex << std::uppercase << uintptr_t(p) << "[0m";
        return s.str();
    }

    static std::string formatFunctionName(const char* functionName)
    {
        return "[96m" + std::string(functionName) + "[0m";
    }

    static std::string indentation()
    {
        return std::string((objectsAlive + 1) * 4, ' ');
    }

public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using size_type = std::make_unsigned_t<typename std::pointer_traits<pointer>::difference_type>;

    size_t id;

    DebugAllocator() noexcept
        : id(nextId++)
    {
        std::cerr << indentation() << "DebugAllocator::" << formatFunctionName(__func__) << '(' << id << ")\n";
        ++objectsAlive;
    }

    template<typename T_rhs>
    DebugAllocator(const DebugAllocator<T_rhs>& rhs) noexcept
        : id(nextId++)
    {
        std::cerr << indentation() << "DebugAllocator::" << formatFunctionName(__func__) << '(' << id << ", " << rhs.id << ")\n";
        ++objectsAlive;
    }

    template<typename T_rhs>
    DebugAllocator& operator=(const DebugAllocator<T_rhs>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        std::cerr << indentation() << id << " = DebugAllocator::" << formatFunctionName(__func__) << '(' << id << ", " << rhs.id << ")\n";
    }

    ~DebugAllocator() noexcept
    {
        --objectsAlive;
        std::cerr << indentation() << "DebugAllocator::" << formatFunctionName(__func__) << '(' << id << ")\n";
    }

    pointer allocate(size_type n) const
    {
        value_type* const p((value_type*) new char[sizeof(value_type) * n]);
        std::cerr << indentation() << formatPointer(p) << " = DebugAllocator::" << formatFunctionName(__func__) << '(' << id << ", " << n << ")\n";
        return p;
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) const noexcept
    {
        std::cerr << indentation() << "DebugAllocator::" << formatFunctionName(__func__) << '(' << id << ", " << formatPointer(p) << ", " << n << ")\n";
        delete[] (value_type*) p;
    }

    bool operator==(const DebugAllocator& rhs) const noexcept
    {
        std::cerr << indentation() << std::boolalpha << true << " = DebugAllocator::" << formatFunctionName(__func__) << '(' << id << ", " << rhs.id << ")\n";
        return true;
    }

    bool operator!=(const DebugAllocator& rhs) const noexcept
    {
        std::cerr << indentation() << std::boolalpha << false << " = DebugAllocator::" << formatFunctionName(__func__) << '(' << id << ", " << rhs.id << ")\n";
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int, DebugAllocator<int>> v{3};
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.emplace_back(1);
    v.insert(std::begin(v) + 2, 4);
    v.erase(std::begin(v) + 3);

    std::string separator;
    for (int& x : v)
    {
        std::cerr << separator << std::move(x);
        separator = ", ";
    }

    std::cerr << '\n';
}
```

GCC / MSVS log:

```
    DebugAllocator::DebugAllocator(0)
        0xF86C50 = DebugAllocator::allocate(0, 1)
    DebugAllocator::~DebugAllocator(0)
    0xF86CA0 = DebugAllocator::allocate(0, 2)
    DebugAllocator::deallocate(0, 0xF86C50, 1)
    0xF86C50 = DebugAllocator::allocate(0, 4)
    DebugAllocator::deallocate(0, 0xF86CA0, 2)
    0xF86C20 = DebugAllocator::allocate(0, 8)
    DebugAllocator::deallocate(0, 0xF86C50, 4)
3, 1, 4, 1
    DebugAllocator::deallocate(0, 0xF86C20, 8)
DebugAllocator::~DebugAllocator(0)
```

clang log:

```
    DebugAllocator::DebugAllocator(0)
        0xD886F0 = DebugAllocator::allocate(0, 1)
        0xD88710 = DebugAllocator::allocate(0, 2)
        DebugAllocator::deallocate(0, 0xD886F0, 1)
        0xD886F0 = DebugAllocator::allocate(0, 4)
        DebugAllocator::deallocate(0, 0xD88710, 2)
        0xD88730 = DebugAllocator::allocate(0, 8)
        DebugAllocator::deallocate(0, 0xD886F0, 4)
3, 1, 4, 1
        DebugAllocator::deallocate(0, 0xD88730, 8)
    DebugAllocator::~DebugAllocator(0)
```

Comment: make_unsigned_t . xcode comlains about it

Comment: Try including `<type_traits>`, and that is a C++14 type if you haven't set that flag

Comment: Could you extract the faulty code into about 20 lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537994/c-template-copy-constructor-on-template-class)

```
template<typename T_rhs>
DebugAllocator(const DebugAllocator<T_rhs>& rhs)
```

does not count as a copy constructor. So a compiler-generated copy-constructor is called that you didn't observe.