# How to utilize template copy&move constructor and assignment operator?

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, default-constructor

Consider the following C++ code with my failed attempt to avoid [preference of non-template copy&move constructors and assignment operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32539424/1915854):

```
template<typename T> class A {
public:
    A() { /* implementation here */ }

    // Remove from the overloads the default copy&move constructors and assignment operators
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
    A& operator=(A&&) = delete;

    // I want these to be used e.g. by std::vector
    template<typename U> A(const A<U>& fellow) { /* implementation here */ }
    template<typename U> A& operator=(const A<U>& fellow) { /* implementation here */ }

    template<typename U> A(A<U>&& fellow) { /* implementation here */ }
    template<typename U> A& operator=(A<U>&& fellow) { /* implementation here */ }        
};
```

However, I get the following error

> attempting to reference a deleted function

when trying to push `A` items to a vector or simply copy-construct like:

```
A<int> a1{};
A<int> a2(a1);
```

UPDATE1: I need template copy&move constructors and assignment operators, because the template argument really just controls some caching, so `A<T1>` can be safely assigned to `A<T2>`.

Comment: Copy/move constructors are never templates. If you don't want the copy/move constructors to do the work, maybe you can delegate. Show what part of the implementation bothers you; it might be better placed outside of any constructor.

Comment: `A<int> a1();` is a function declaration ("most vexing parse...") also all the constructors are private

Comment: instead of `delete` regular copy/move constructor/assignment, forward them to template implementation.

Comment: @Jarod42, what specifically do you mean by forwarding? It seems this is what I'm asking for - how to forward.

Comment: @SergeRogatch - you can forwarding adding an unused argument (with default value) in template constructor

Comment: Only **defaulted** special member function defined as deleted do not participate to overload resolution.

Answer (score 5):

You can make compiler happy by declaring deleted copy constructor / assignment operator with alternative signature which will not cause this overload to be selected but will prevent generation of constructor / assignment operator by compiler:

```
template<typename T> class A
{ public:
    A() { /* implementation here */ }

    // Remove from the implicit declaration of the default copy&move constructors and assignment operators
    A(A volatile const &) = delete;
    A & operator =(A volatile const &) = delete;

    // I want these to be used e.g. by std::vector
    template<typename U> A(A<U> const & fellow) { /* implementation here */ }
    template<typename U> A & operator =(A<U> const & fellow) { /* implementation here */ return *this;}

    template<typename U> A(A<U> && fellow) { /* implementation here */ }
    template<typename U> A & operator =(A<U> && fellow) { /* implementation here */ return *this; }        
};
int main()
{
    A<int> a1{};
    A<int> a2{a1};
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dxlg8bSECAEunymf)

> **15.8.1 Copy/move constructors [class.copy.ctor]**
>   1. A non-template constructor for `class X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments

Answer (score 1):

A minimal example of a copy constructor that delegate the execution to the template constructor using a second unused (and defaulted) argument

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct A
 {
   A()
    { }

   A (A const & a0) : A{a0, 0}
    { }

   template<typename U>
   A (A<U> const &, int = 0)
    { std::cout << "template constructor" << std::endl; }
 };

int main()
 {
   A<int>  a0;
   A<int>  a1{a0};
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks

> What about `operator=`? Trying to add a dummy parameter gives compiler errors `binary 'operator =' has too many parameters and 'operator =' cannot have default parameters`

For `operator=()` I propose to "delegate" (not in the meaning of delegating constructor, in this case) both operators to a normal method; a template one.

Something as

```
   template <typename U>
   A & assign (A<U> const &)
    { /* do assignment */ return *this; }

   A & operator= (A const & a0)
    { return assign(a0); }

   template <typename U>
   A & operator= (A<U> const & a0)
    { return assign(a0); }
```

Maybe the `assign()` method can be a `private` one.

Or better, as suggested by Jarod42 (thanks), directly calling the template operator from the not-template one

```
template <typename U>
A & operator= (A<U> const & a0)
 { /* do assignment */ return *this; }

A & operator= (A const & a0)
 { return operator=<T>(a0); }
```

Comment: What about `operator=`? Trying to add a dummy parameter gives compiler errors `binary 'operator =' has too many parameters` and `'operator =' cannot have default parameters`

Comment: @SergeRogatch - answer improved; hope this helps.

Comment: @max66: or `return operator=<T>(rhs);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - You're right: works and it's simpler. Thanks.