# C++ template copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor, move-constructor

In [C++ template copy constructor on template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537994/c-template-copy-constructor-on-template-class), I find that template copy constructor can't be done. I try to do it and manage to succeed. I think that it is because move constructor is included in the class. When I comment the move constructor, it doesn't compile:`error: use of deleted function 'matrix::Matrix<TYPE>::Matrix(const matrix::Matrix<TYPE>&) [with TYPE = double]`. I'm using MinGW(GCC 6.3.0) on Windows 10. 
header:

```
namespace matrix {
enum IDENTITY { BLANK, I_1, I_2, I_3, I_4};
template<class TYPE = double>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(const Matrix& m) = delete;   //delete normal copy constructor
    template <class U> Matrix(const Matrix<U>& m);   //template copy constructor
    ~Matrix();

    Matrix(Matrix&& m) noexcept{   //move constructor
        std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    .
    .//Some other functions declaration
    .
private:
    unsigned int rows_ = 0;
    unsigned int cols_ = 0;
    TYPE *data_;
};
.
.//Member functions definition
.
```

main:

```
int main(){
    matrix::Matrix<int> m2(matrix::I_4); //normal constructor, Identity matrix 4x4
    matrix::Matrix<double> m1 = m2;   //copy constructor, error here if without move constructor
    m1(0,1) = 2;   //assign m1(0,1) = 2
    //show matrix
    std::cout << m1;
    std::cout << m2;
}
```

result:

```
 1     2     0     0
 0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     1

 1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     1

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.062 s
```

The question is:

1. Why move constructor make template copy constructor doable?
2. Are there any consequences of doing this? Is it safe to do this?
3. Are there any other way to write template copy constructor?

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?  A modified version of your code works with the move constructor copied out: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6dbc7966fd21627f

Comment: If you want your code to work with C++14 (used by gcc6.3) make `matrix::Matrix<double> m1 {m2};`.

Comment: *The* copy constructor of a class `T` is a non-template that takes a parameter of type `T&` or `const T&`. Any other constructor is not a copy constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver I copy your code on my PC and it give the same error. Perhap it is because of the compiler.

Comment: @rafix07 That work. I try with `matrix::Matrix<double>  m1 (m2)` and that also work. It seems that `matrix::Matrix<double> m1 = m2` is treated differently, do you know why?

Comment: @PhạmQuangTrường Sounds like it is a compiler bug.  Any chance you can update your comp]iler?

Comment: @NathanOliver This is already the latest version of MinGW. If this is a bug then there is not much I can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you defined a "constructor". And it isn't a "copy constructor".
And following errors are the result of it:
- if you declare only move constructor (without copy constructor), the copy constructor is "deleted".
- if you define "any constructor" then the compiler creates default copy constuctor.

Comment: "if you declare only move constructor (without copy constructor), the copy constructor is "deleted"", do you have source for this?